# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) (Cython, TeamSpeak3)

Tags: python, sdk, cython, access-violation, teamspeak

My aim for now is creating team speak 3 manager service (that switches the users by channels an others):
So I created wrapper of TS3 SDK lib (wrapped with Cython for Python): https://mega.nz/#!pQdFjIwD!1vg8DPsFtYR4icVqWXzvpdbAQ47-n-aPz2niRkTU4fY (main module: http://pastebin.com/PywhH4bf )
In this wrapper I used test connection in module. To test this module just import this.

And I got message in python console (after call the `ts3client_startConnection`): `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)` (access violation)

Also as I see the TS3 callbacks are called from non-main thread.

With this log:

```
2016-08-16 10:14:20.862577|INFO    |              |   |TeamSpeak 3 Client 3.0.3 (2015-03-30 11:30:36) SDK
2016-08-16 10:14:20.863574|INFO    |              |   |SystemInformation: Windows 9 8664 {6} {3} {9600}  (9600) x64 (AMD or Intel) Binary: 32bit
2016-08-16 10:14:20.863574|INFO    |              |   |Using hardware aes
2016-08-16 10:14:20.876587|DEBUG   |Direct Sound  |   |setting timer resolution to 1ms
2016-08-16 10:14:20.892602|ERROR   |SoundBckndIntf|   |Could not load "ts3soundbackend_isSupported" from backend dynamic library
spawn connection handler
mode
Default capture mode: b'Windows Audio Session'

('Default capture device: %s %s\n', b'\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x84\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd (\xd0\xa3\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb9\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe \xd1\x81 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb6\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb9 High Definition Audio)', b'{0.0.1.00000000}.{c28d826f-9cd5-414b-a018-bbfc0cbc1298}')
2016-08-16 10:14:20.905616|DEBUG   |Windows Audio Session|   |WAS::openDevice-enter
2016-08-16 10:14:20.912622|DEBUG   |Windows Audio Session|   |WAS Buffer size: 896
2016-08-16 10:14:20.912622|DEBUG   |Windows Audio Session|   |WAS::openDevice-leave
2016-08-16 10:14:20.912622|INFO    |PreProSpeex   |1  |Speex version: speex-1.2beta3
2016-08-16 10:14:20.912622|DEBUG   |Windows Audio Session|   |WAS::startDevice-enter
2016-08-16 10:14:20.913622|DEBUG   |Windows Audio Session|   |WAS::startDevice-leave
Default playback mode: b'Windows Audio Session'

('Default playback device: %s %s\n', b'\xd0\x94\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8 (\xd0\xa3\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb9\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe \xd1\x81 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb6\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb9 High Definition Audio)', b'{0.0.0.00000000}.{cb324415-bf79-473b-9a59-69a1ca4bfe56}')
2016-08-16 10:14:20.913622|DEBUG   |Windows Audio Session|   |WAS::openDevice-enter
2016-08-16 10:14:20.918627|DEBUG   |Windows Audio Session|   |WAS Buffer size: 896
2016-08-16 10:14:20.918627|DEBUG   |Windows Audio Session|   |WAS::openDevice-leave
2016-08-16 10:14:20.918627|DEBUG   |Windows Audio Session|   |WAS::startDevice-enter
2016-08-16 10:14:20.918627|DEBUG   |Windows Audio Session|   |WAS::startDevice-leave
creating identity
Using identity: b'295V/MObSjZ2wIe+dMWhUoLET/UpS6ENHlhWSVdYYSZ5UnQTU3dneUFQLAF/FDVRBXkaFVFeAH10V1cDQn0Gd3BVYgFgXwV4IgxjOVB2DCwtET9TfgcaA31GE1MBZFxLBXtgDHd9WHFka0NJUUQweGprQnp2cjNrSkxBMXJaazRWeDJMTkRUOUlXcVVyZ0p0WnpDU0lDOVlRPT0='

Client lib initialized and running

Connect status changed: 1 1 0

2016-08-16 10:14:20.926635|DEVELOP |PktHandler    |   |Puzzle solve time: 7
Connect status changed: 1 2 0

Connect status changed: 1 3 0

Connect status changed: 1 4 0
```

Also I got not repeatable random errors:

```
Fatal Python error: GC object already tracked
```

and

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
```

Comment: Your first link is broken (seems to need a log-in). Although I'd guess even with the link this is still a long way from a useful _minimal_ example.

Comment: @DavidW  a now link is valid.

Comment: @DavidW all code are just wrapped with cython ts3 sdk library with minimal connection example. How to do that more *minimal*?

Comment: I would try adding `with gil` to those callback functions i.e. `cdef void onConnectStatusChangeEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, int newStatus, unsigned int errorNumber) with gil:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to lack of a verifiable example, this is a little bit of guessing.

If those handler functions are called from a thread that is created by the C library (ts3client_*), the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) has not been properly acquired by the time python functions are called.

Adding `with gil` like

```
cdef void onConnectStatusChang‌​eEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHand‌​lerID,
                                     int newStatus, 
                                     unsigned int errorNumber) with gil:
```

may help.

There is also no code at the end of `__main__()`, it might be better that the main thread is at least idling.

```
if (error != ERROR_ok):
    print("Error connecting to server: %d\n"% error)

print("Client lib initialized and running\n")
```

The following lines could be added after the print call for a quick test

```
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: Adding `with gil` entails a complete freeze of python application. And after some changes in code (after wich I got freeze), I got message `Fatal Python error: drop_gil: GIL is not locked` and again `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`.

To test application just run `compile.py` and after `test.py` (and I updated archive, now `with gil`)